# Delete icon does not delete the item 1st time, it takes two clicks to delete the item

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

The first time i click on delete, the id is undefined. But the id is available on 2nd click and it deletes the item.

Feed.js:

```
const Feed = ({ username }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { _id, username: currentUsername } = useSelector(
    (state) => state.auth.user
  );
  const { posts } = useSelector((state) => state.post);

  const fetchPosts = async () => {
    username ? dispatch(getProfilePosts(username)) : dispatch(getTimeline(_id));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchPosts();
  }, [username, _id, dispatch]);

  const handleDelete = async (id) => {
    dispatch(deletePost(id));
    fetchPosts();
  };

  return (
    <div className="feed">
      <div className="feed-wrapper">
        {!username && <Share />}
        {username !== currentUsername || <Share />}
        {posts.length > 0 ? (
          posts.map((x) => (
            <Post key={Math.random()} post={x} handleDelete={handleDelete} />
          ))
        ) : (
          <div className="progress">
            <CircularProgress size={25} color="primary" />
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Post.js:

```
const Post = ({ post, handleDelete }) => {
  const { _id, userId, desc, img, likes, comment } = post;
  const [likeCount, setLikeCount] = useState(likes?.length || 0);
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const { user: currentUser } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const PF = process.env.REACT_APP_PUBLIC_FOLDER;

  const _isLiked = likes?.includes(currentUser._id);
  const [isLiked, setIsLiked] = useState(_isLiked);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const likeHandler = () => {
    _id && dispatch(likeDislikePost(currentUser._id, _id));
    setLikeCount(isLiked ? likeCount - 1 : likeCount + 1);
    setIsLiked(!isLiked);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUser = async () => {
      if (userId) {
        const res = await axiosClient.get(`/users?userId=${userId}`);
        setUser(res.data);
      }
    };
    fetchUser();
  }, [userId]);

  return (
    <>
      {
        <div className="post">
          <div className="post-wrapper">
            <div className="post-top">
              <div className="post-top-left">
                <Link to={`/profile/${user?.username}`}>
                  <img
                    src={user?.profilePicture || PF + "person/noAvatar.png"}
                    alt=""
                    className="post-profile-img"
                  />
                </Link>
                <span className="post-username">{user?.username}</span>
                <span className="post-date">{format(post.createdAt)}</span>
              </div>
              <div className="post-top-right">
                <Tooltip title="Delete" arrow>
                  <IconButton onClick={() => handleDelete(_id)}>
                    <DeleteIcon />
                  </IconButton>
                </Tooltip>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="post-center">
              <span className="post-text">{desc}</span>
              <img className="post-img" src={img} />
            </div>
            <div className="post-bottom">
              <div className="post-bottom-left">
                <img
                  src={`${PF}like.png`}
                  onClick={likeHandler}
                  alt=""
                  className="like-icon"
                />
                <img
                  src={`${PF}heart.png`}
                  onClick={likeHandler}
                  alt=""
                  className="like-icon"
                />
                <span className="post-like-counter">
                  {likeCount} people like it
                </span>
              </div>
              <div className="post-bottom-right">
                <span className="post-comment-text">{comment} comments</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      }
    </>
  );
};
```

postActions.js:

```
export const deletePost = (id) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await axiosClient.delete(`/posts/${id}`);
    console.log(data);
    dispatch({ type: "DELETE_POST", id });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

I need the items to be deleted the 1st time i click the button, but the id passed to the handleDelete function is undefined on the first click. But it is present on the 2nd click and it deletes the item.

Comment: You need to post enough code such that the problem can be reproduced.  For example you use a variable `_id` in the delete but you did not specify how it was defined.

Comment: @possum: thanks for letting me know. i have updated my question with full code.

Comment: From what I can see of the code if you are passing an undefined id value to the `handleDelete` handler then you've post data that has undefined `_id` property for at least one render cycle. Can you [edit] to share a complete [mcve] that include the data you are rendering content from?

Answer (score -1):

Not sure about the exact cause but I can speculate that event delegation issue due to Tooltip component you're using I'll suggest try removing the ToolTipe componenet first:

```html
<div className="post-top-right">
  <IconButton onClick={()=> handleDelete(_id)}>
    <DeleteIcon />
  </IconButton>
</div>
```

And if it works try moving the tooltip inside the button component something like this:

```html
<div className="post-top-right">
  <IconButton onClick={()=> handleDelete(_id)}>
    <Tooltip title="Delete" arrow>
      <DeleteIcon />
    </Tooltip>
  </IconButton>
</div>
```

Comment: removed tooltip element, still not working. Require 2 clicks to delete